# Daily reputation limit in Beta

Tags: support, reputation

Some users are exceeding 200 rep / day. Is there an enforced rep limit in Beta? If not, when does it kick in -- I'm sure some of us would like to make use of an unlimited/exemption period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reputation cap (200 rep/day) applies to both beta site and graduated sites.

But any additional reputation you earn from "accepted answers" and bounties are immune from the reputation cap. So it is possible to earn more than 200 reputation per day if you hit the cap but have addition points earned from accepted answers and bounties.

Answer (score 0):

The reputation limit is the same for beta and "normal" websites.

Comment: "You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given day. Accepted answers and bounties are counted separately (source). Reputation "lost" from the reputation cap is not awarded on following days." http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Comment: Perhaps then my misunderstanding is not a 200 total but  maintained separately across upvotes and accepts? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/

Comment: Sorry I made myself wrong. Updated my answer.